# PHP french word displays special characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have french words stored in database,however while displaying in browser the characters are not properly displayed,displays like � and so on..How convert such word exactly to french words same as entered in database using PHP ? I have tried html_entity_decode(),works for some of the cases.

Comment: Some Code would be helpful to spot the error...

Comment: @Rizier123 I am useing one function                                          function dispContent_2($val){
 $val = stripslashes(trim($val));
 $content = html_entity_decode($val);
 //$content = htmlentities($content, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1'); //ENT_NOQUOTES
 //$content = html_entity_decode($content, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1');
 return $content;
}

Comment: Please use the edit button under your question! (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27498334/edit)

Comment: And the output code by itself is useless without elaborating how you mangled the data beforehand. Why the html_entity_decode? And while Latin-1 suffices for french, you better just use UTF-8 throughout if you're unversed.